# Anchor not scrolling correctly

Tags: css, scroll, fragment-identifier

I have a layout something along the lines of :

```
<div class="banner"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

My banner has `position:fixed;` and is roughly `200px` high.

The problem is that when I click a link with a fragment identifier, the page scrolls and the anchor (with the identifier) sits at the top of the page, *behind* the banner instead of under the banner where it can be seen.

Is there something (CSS or jQuery) that I am missing ?

Comment: Can you post your CSS and the html where the anchor is?

Comment: you can only compensate for this if you use javascript scrolling and add/subtract the height of the banner accordingly.. that is the whole point of `position:fixed`.. to get it out of the normal document flow.. Alternatively, you could wrap the rest of your site with a div, and style it so you only scroll inside that..

Comment: A working example of the problem would also help immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dup of [Div anchors scrolling too far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501025/div-anchors-scrolling-too-far)

For the requests to see sample code, I've put a full sample page here:  https://gist.github.com/denised/5924370.

The key bit is the presence of two divs (#header and #mainbody) and the following bit of css (which I believe is a fairly standard way to create a fixed header):

```
#header {
  position:fixed; 
  left:0; right:0; top:0;
  background-color: #F0F0E8;
  z-index:2;
}

#mainbody { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}
```