# Google Closure equivalent to jQuery $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 800});

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, google-closure

The code in question animates a page scroll to a particular point on the page. As the title says, I want the Google Closure equivalent to the following jQuery:

> $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 800});

It  says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303405/difference-between-html-body-animate-and-body-animate) that `html, body` allows for browser inconsistencies, and that `$(document)` is equivalent.

I have tried the following:

```
var anim = new goog.fx.dom.Scroll(document, [0, 0], [0, 800], 400);
anim.play();
```

I've also tried with `document.body`.

There are no demos and a dismal lack of information on `goog.fx.dom.Scroll` on the web.

Comment: i'd assume based on the api you would need to call it twice, once with `document.body` and again with `document.querySelector("html")` but i've never used that library.

Comment: You might be better off asking closure-library-discuss@

Comment: For the record, I ended up going Vanilla by using a modified, hard-coded, de-jQueried version of the jQuery smooth-scroll plugin by Chris Ferdinandi.

Answer (score 6):

The way to make this goog.fx.Scroll class  work with the document (body or HTML) work is by passing the document scroll element this way:

```
/**
 * Document scroll element obtained from goog.dom
 * @type {Element}
 * @private
 */
let documentScrollElement_ = goog.dom.getDocumentScrollElement()

/**
 * Function triggered by any target to start scrolling
 * @param  {Event} e Triggered event
 * @private
 */
function scrollTrigger_(e) {
  let googScroll = new goog.fx.dom.Scroll(
    this.documentScrollElement_,
    [0, 0],
    [0, 800],
    400);

  googScroll.play();
}
```

Just so you know the Scroll class has this optional parameter to add easing to the scroll. You should new the class like this:

```
let googScroll = new goog.fx.dom.Scroll(
    this.documentScrollElement_,
    [0, 0],
    [0, 800],
    400,
    goog.fx.easing.inAndOut(t)); // Note that you need to import or require the goog.fx.easing object
```

I know this is an old question but I ran into this same problem and managed to make it work so I thought it was worth it to answer this.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source code](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/source/closure/goog/fx/dom.js.src.html) this should work if you use `document.body` and you haven't done anything weird to the styling, but you will need to debug to find the issue.

Start by manually changing `document.body.scrollTop`, if that doesn't work this scroll animation won't be able to do anything about it.

Also, put a breakpoint in `goog.fx.dom.Scroll.prototype.updateStyle` and `goog.fx.Animation.prototype.play` and see if they fire and what happens.

Have fun.