# Scroll is Not Working Inside SetTimeout() with Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an scroll to element snippet as:

```
$('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
},1000);
```

which is working perfectly but I need to run it after few seconds on getting into the page (with delay), so I used `setTimeout()` to get this but now the page jumps to the section (hash) without scrolling or prompting any error message.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
  },1000);   
}, 2000);
```

can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and why this is not working with delay?!

Comment: How can it work? window.location.hash returns a part of url after # symbol, scrollTop property requires integer value..

Comment: @philosophocat, `$(window.location.hash)` - jQuery selector, `hash` here something like `#hash`, so this valid selector for `id` in jQuery. then just get `offset` and `top` property

Comment: Can you provide snippet, or jsfiddle that can reproduce your problem?

Comment: I do not think that `html,body` is correct. Maybe you meant `html body` (space instead of comma)?

Comment: @AlexisWilke, if this incorrect why this work _without_ timeout?

Comment: @Grundy, if you're right, that's interesting, but unsafe solution: not really good idea to rely on hash without any kind of checking and it can be a key to issue: element just missed.

Comment: Ah. I see why. The answer suggests you use `$(document)` though.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303405/difference-between-html-body-animate-and-body-animate

Comment: I just tested and your code worked just fine in SeaMonkey (2.39) and Firefox (44) and Chromium (48)... What browser are you testing with? Except that I put a direct name for the hash instead of using the window hash (where you should already have been scrolled to since that's what the hash is for in the URL...)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
  $('html,body').delay( 2000 ).animate({
     scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
  },1000);
```

Other option is:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
      },1000);
});
```

Comment: thansks mkmnstr, I tried this but the result i same as using the `setTimeout()` with no error message!

Comment: @Behseini just added another option, check and let me know