# Toggling a class after JQ animation completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems understanding why my `toggleClass` inside of the function after the animate doesn't seem to trigger properly.  When looking at console, you will be able to see that the element `menu` is changing states, which leads me to think it is toggling both on and off quickly.  Once the scroll animation completes, `toggleClass` works as to be expected.

My script code is as follows:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // initToggle();
    stickyNav();
    toggleMenu();

  });

  function stickyNav() {

      var navOffset = $('.nav-bar').offset().top;

      $(window).scroll(function() {
          var nav = $('.nav-bar');
          var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

          if (scroll >= navOffset) {
              nav.addClass('fixed');
          } else {
              nav.removeClass('fixed');
          }
      });
  }

  function toggleMenu() {
      $('.nav-menu').click(function() {
          if (!$('.nav-bar').hasClass('fixed')) {
              $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.nav-bar').offset().top}, '800',
              function() {
                  $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
                  $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
              });
          } else {
              $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
              $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
          }
      });
  }
```

[HERE is a "working" codepen of my code which better displays the issue I'm having.](http://codepen.io/ekfuhrmann/pen/rrVwqx)

Comment: What *exactly* do you expect to happen? List out what you expect to happen, what **is** happening, and the steps to take to see the problem.

Comment: I believe your animation fires twice, once for `html` and once for `body`.

Comment: @showdev That was exactly what the issue was.  Boy do I feel silly, considering I even mentioned it looked to be firing twice but couldn't figure out quite why. 

Also, that second comment of yours regarding the `when` and `then` is really neat.  Not sure it's entirely necessary in this instance as I was calling the animate twice, but could be helpful in the future.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: This is also relevant: [Callback of .animate() gets called twice jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790752/callback-of-animate-gets-called-twice-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

@showdev linked to a similar question relating to using `promise()`.

Got the script to work by changing it to the following:

```
function toggleMenu() {
    $('.nav-menu').click(function() {
        if (!$('.nav-bar').hasClass('fixed')) {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.nav-bar').offset().top}, '800').promise().done(function() {
                $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
                $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
            });
        } else {
            $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
            $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303405/difference-between-html-body-animate-and-body-animate), there may be browser compatibility issues when only using one of the selectors.

Comment: Yeah, I used the link you suggested and got it to work via `promise()`.  I'm going to mark your duplicate as the correct answer.  Thanks again!